# Is it possible to use the offline export in stockchart?

Tags: highcharts, export, jstockchart

Or there is another option for client export without using highcharts servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exporting and offline-exporting also work for Highstock. Example:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7j50fwtd/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

Comment: Thank you. additional question: I downloaded the 3 DLLs to my local server and I get errors while running.
Which additional DLLs need to be downloaded in order for them to work?

Comment: Hi @אסתר גוטפרוינד, Please create another question with `highcharts` tag and add more detailed description of the problem there.